# How to serve <use> SVG-symbols with Webpack and Vue.js?

Tags: svg, webpack, vue.js

I use Webpack in conjunction with Vue.js.
In the map.svg file I store all the SVG icons in the form like this:

```
<symbol id="someID"><path></symbol>
<symbol id="otherID"><path></symbol>
```

In the code I use a construct like this with SVG4Everybody-plugin:

```
<svg><use xlink:href="map.svg#someID"></svg>
```

But this does not work, because Webpack does not distribute SVG sprites. What to do in this situation? Thanks!

---

Webpack 3.6.0
Vue 2.5.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must add the SVG sprite to HTML using the `<object>`

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="map.svg">
   Your browser does not support SVG
</object>
```

`Your browser does not support SVG` - failback for old browsers

After adding a sprite to the HTML, you can use the icons from the sprite:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24"> 
  <use xlink:href="map.svg#someID">
 </svg>
```

Use the `viewBox` options to match the size of the icons.